# How to use .net core dependency injection in multiprojects solution?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, castle-windsor, .net-core

I'm new to asp.net core.
What I'm trying to do is to build multi projects solution and use dependency injection to pass interfaces between projects.
What I know is that in ASP.NET core project we have `ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs` file to register our interfaces and their implementations like this:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
   // Add framework services.
   services.AddMvc();
   services.AddTransient<IMyInterface,MyImplementation>();
   .....
 }
```

This is good if you have classes all in the same project, but what if I have multi projects ?
Usually what I'll do is create separate project with installers (Windsor installers) to register the needed interfaces and their implementations.

In .net core we can do this by creating static `ServiceCollection();` and get from it static `IServiceProvider` to use it any time to get any service you register:

```
public static IServiceCollection _serviceCollection { get; private set; }
public static IServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; private set; }
public static RegisterationMethod() {
   _serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

   _serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMyInterface,MyImplementation>();
   .....
   serviceProvider = _serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
}

public T GetService<T>() where T : class
{
   return serviceProvider.GetService<T>();
}
```

Now we call `RegisterationMethod` from ower startup project and continue to develop as usual with always registering the services in this class.
The problem in this approach is if I used it in ASP.NET core project I'll have two places to register the services, this one and the one in the `startup.cs` file which has `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` .
You may say,

> OK pass `IServiceCollection` you had in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` to the `RegisterationMethod` you previously created, in this way you're using the same services collection that ASP.NET using.

But in this way I'll be tight coupled to the dependency injection module of the `.net core`.

Is there more clean way to do this ? or should I have replace the default DI with `Windsor` for example ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ...in ASP.NET core project[s] we have ConfigureServices... to register our interfaces and their implementations... This is good if you have classes all in the same project, but what if I have multi projects?

It doesn't matter that you have multi projects. The same principle applies:

**Put your composition root in your application, as close to the entry point as possible.**

Lets assume that you have a single application that references several class libraries. In your application's `Startup` class, use `ConfigureServices` to register all of the dependencies. In each of the class library projects, use constructor injection. It does not matter whether your classes live in the same or in different projects.

> OK pass IServiceCollection you had in ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) to the RegisterationMethod you previously created, in this way you're using the same services collection that ASP.NET using.

Yes, that's the way to do it. Here is [an example from the github.com/aspnet/logging repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/9506ccc3f3491488fe88010ef8b9eb64594abf95/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L20-L31):

```
public static IServiceCollection AddLogging(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (services == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>());
    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));

    return services;
}
```

## Based on your comments...

...it sounds like you are trying to avoid having a [**composition root**](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) in your application. The composition root is the single location where we register dependencies with the dependency injection container. The composition root is placed as close as possible to the application's entry point (the `ConfigureServices` method, for instance) and it belongs in the application not in its libraries.

Comment: I have asp.net core project, and multi layers: (services , repositories , ..), the way you suggest is to reference all my interfaces and implementations in this web project, I don't this it's a good way to do it right ?  that's why I want to create separate project to register all of them.

Comment: @dabbas Let me see if I am understanding correctly. You have a single application (`MyApp`). You also have a bunch of class libraries, which include services and repositories (`MyService`, `MyRepository`, et cetera). Is that right?

Comment: Yes correct, so that `MyApp` will actually only have reference to `MyServices` to get\set data and `MyServices` only reference `MyRepositories` ...

Comment: @Dabbas Based on that, it seems correct to register all of the dependencies inside `ConfigureServices` and to reference all of your interfaces and implementations in the web project. Why do you not think this is right?

Comment: I don't think this is a good practice, this way you have access to `MyRepositories` implementations, so why to you need repository layer ? previously I used to have core project that register all layers and call the registration method in it from my start project only.

Comment: @dabbas My sense is that, inside the `Startup` class, yes, you have a reference to `MyRepositories`, but that's only to register it as the implementation of `IMyRepository`. Through the rest of the application and its class libraries, you will program against interfaces. The `Startup` class is where you register the services that implement those interfaces. This seems reasonable to me. The repository layer, in this case, will hide the data layer's implementation from the services.

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I'm looking for, I need a way to get the services collection in another project without creating new one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126417/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-dabbas).

Comment: @Dabbas: The application is the place where you wire up the DI, because from application to application it may vary how you use it so its impossible to let the libraries handle/bootstrap their own. ASP.NET Core libraries usually abstract this behind a `AddXxx()` method and `.UseXxx` (middleware registration), so you can just do `services.AddMyAppBusinessServices()` etc. in your Startup class. There is no out of the box module support like Unity or Windsor, you have to write extension methods or your own module system or use 3rd party IoC container

Comment: @Tseng I thought I could do this in some way that I get the instance of `IServiceCollection' and register my services with it, without referencing all the interfaces and implementations to the main app, looks like you suggestion is the closest to what I wanted, please add it as an answer to choose it.

Comment: @Dabbas: Nothing prevents you from doing so, create a class, pass `IServiceCollection` to it during startup and register it here. But that's no different from creating a static class in your library project with a signature of `public static IServiceCollection AddMyBusinessServices(this IServiceCollection services)` and register your stuff inside, then put `services.AddMyBusinessServices()` in your Startup.cs. You need the reference anyways. If you don't want the classes to be instantiated in the application project, mark them or their constructor as `internal`