# How to create an instance of UserManager in ASP.NET MVC Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to create an instance of UserManager in Mvc Core 2 as I did on ASP.NET MVC 6 with following code:

```
var UserManager = new UserManager<DbUser>(new UserStore<DbUser>(this) );
```

I receive many errors according to missing parameters, Is there a proper way of getting the instance outside of the controller?

Comment: Do you start with a new application or are you trying migration? Is it not possible to let it inject bi DI Framework like   public YourClass(IUserManager userManager)
  { ... You need also the right configuration for it...

Comment: Yes, I was able to get it from DI, but I am spouse to seed few admin users in starting the application,Yet the seed method was inside DbContext which was in another assembly and I did not have access to DI

Answer (score 4):

> I did not have access to DI.

this explanation is incorrect, you can inject `UserManager` in another assembly [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196407/how-to-use-net-core-dependency-injection-in-multiprojects-solution).

Just create a service for seeding your data for example:

```
public interface IInitializationService
{
    void Seed();
}

public class InitializationService : IInitializationService
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public InitializationService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public void Seed()
    {
        // more code
    }
}
```

Register service in Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<IInitializationService, InitializationService>();

        services.AddMvc();
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
        // more code ...

        var scopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var identityDbInitialize = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IInitializationService>();
            identityDbInitialize.Seed();
        }

      // more code ...
 }
```